# Java->C# BigInteger + Math Conversion

Tags: java, c#, math, biginteger

I am attempting to convert some BigInteger objects and math from Java to C#.

The Java flow is as follows:

```
1. Construct 2 BigIntegers from a base-10 string (i.e. 0-9 values).
2. Construct a third BigInteger from an inputted byte array.
3. Create a fourth BigInteger as third.modPow(first, second).
4. Return the byte result of fourth.
```

The main complications in converting to C# seem to consist of endianness and signed/unsigned values.

I have tried a couple different ways to convert the initial 2 BigIntegers from Java->C#. I believe that using the base-10 string with BigInteger.Parse will work as intended, but I am not completely sure.

Another complication comes from the use of a BinaryReader/BinaryWriter implementation, in C#, that is already big-endian (like Java). I use the BR/BW to supply the byte array to create the third BigInteger and consume the byte array produced from the modPow (the fourth BigInteger).

I have tried reversing the byte arrays for input and output in every way, and still do not get the expected output.

Java:

```
public static byte[] doMath(byte[] input)
{
    BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger("BASE-10-STRING");
    BigInteger mod = new BigInteger("BASE-10-STRING");

    BigInteger bigInput = new BigInteger(input);

    return bigInput.modPow(exponent, mod).toByteArray();
}
```

C#:

```
public static byte[] CSharpDoMath(byte[] input)
{
    BigInteger exponent = BigInteger.Parse("BASE-10-STRING");
    BigInteger mod = BigInteger.Parse("BASE-10-STRING");

    // big->little endian
    byte[] reversedBytes = input.Reverse().ToArray();

    BigInteger bigInput = new BigInteger(reversedBytes);

    BigInteger output = BigInteger.ModPow(bigInput, exponent, mod);

    // little->big endian
    byte[] bigOutput = output.ToByteArray().Reverse().ToArray();

    return bigOutput;
}
```

I need the same output from both.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. As in : please add  example data that shows actual and expected output.